# Converting from Python to F# recursive function?

Tags: python, f#, f#-interactive

I am trying to convert this Python code into F# without using immutable variables or `List.map`. I am still a newbie to this.

```
def findMatches(s,l):
    temp=[]
    for i in l:
        if i[0]==s:
            temp.append(i[1])
    temp.sort()
    return temp

l=findMatches("A",[("A",5),("AA",9),("BB",6),("A",0)])
print(l)
```

I've started with:

```
let findMatches s l =
    for e1, e2 in list do
        if e1 = s then ...
```

Not totally if I'm going in the right direction or where to go next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, it is somewhat of a common practice to mutate ("change", "update") your data as you go along - like you're doing with your `temp` list, mutating it at every step. Although it is generally frowned upon even in Python, the language itself makes it very easy, and therefore very tempting.

In F# mutating the data is still possible, but the language makes it hard. On purpose. Well, not *that* hard - it's just a few extra characters, - but at least mutating data is not the default. This is a generally better approach, as even the Python community now recognizes.

Instead, the F# way (and, just in general, the *functional* way) is not to mutate the data, but to create new data by transforming old ones. As in, what functions do (where by "functions" I mean "mathematical functions").

In particular, what your Python loop seems to be doing is (1) *filtering* the input list by `i[0]` and then (2) transforming (usually called "mapping") each element by throwing away `i[0]` and leaving only `i[1]`, and then (3) sorting. This can be written in F# like this:

```
let findMatches s l =
    l
    |> List.filter (fun (e1, _) -> e1 == s)  // filtering
    |> List.map (fun (_, e2) -> e2)          // mapping
    |> List.sort
```

Instead of "building up" the list by repeatedly mutating it, this program creates the resulting list by transforming the input list thrice: filtering, then mapping, then sorting. Another thing to note is that the transformations themselves are built up from smaller pieces: the transformation of the whole list is achieved by transforming a transformation of a single element.

For simple cases like this (except the sorting), F# also provides special syntax - so-called "list comprehensions". It is syntactic sugar, which behind the scenes performs transformations similar to the above, but the syntax is (arguably) more readable:

```
let findMatches s l =
    [ for e1, e2 in l do
        if e1 == s then yield e2
    ]
    |> List.sort
```

Note that, although this looks almost identical to your Python program, the meaning is subtly different. Instead of "do this, then do that" (aka "imperative style"), this program says "the result depends on the input in this way" (aka "functional style").

Answer (score 0):

The most direct mapping from the Python example code to F# I could think of:

```
// I tend to specify the signatures of methods as I find it helpful
let findMatches (s : 'K) (l : seq<'K*'V>): seq<'V> =
  // ResizeArray is an alias for System.Collections.Generic.List<_>
  let temp = ResizeArray ()
  for e1, e2 in l do
    if e1 = s then
      temp.Add e2
  temp.Sort ()
  // F# don't do implicit upcasts like C# so an explicit upcast from
  //  ResizeArray to seq
  upcast temp
```

As mentioned by Fyodor in F# the idiom (ie the common approach) is to avoid mutability and prefer built-in higher-order functions (like filter and map) to process lists.